# What are the security risks with including Google Map API key in gradle?

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

Years back, Google instructed developers to add their google map keys to the buildTypes in gradle. It looked similar to the following:

in build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"your_dev_key"]
    }
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"prod_key"]
    }
}
```

and then in manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="${google_map_key}"/>
```

Some developers would even not use placeholders and add the Google Map key directly as a String. Today, Google has different instructions that I believe they added due to Firebase emergence.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

The new way is to add you keys to a google-services.json file that can be downloaded and added to your project from firebase. The question I have is, are there security issues with exposing your Google Maps API key in gradle? The new way and newer libraries that include API keys try to avoid adding it to Gradle and/or the manifest. Is it coincidental, or is there a security reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an API key for Google Maps Android API you have to set a restriction that consists of the package name and SHA1 fingerprint.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#key-std-details

In gradle you expose an API key, but you don't expose the restriction that was applied in the Cloud developer console. That means if somebody steals an API key they cannot use it as they won't have the same SHA1 fingerprint and they cannot know what restriction you applied in your developer console.

From this point of view including an API key for Google Maps Android API in gradle is secure.