# Android apps reversing: Security risk of exposing API keys

Tags: security, android-security, reversing

When you reverse apk files you find API keys/token somewhere in properties, manifest, strings etc. Sometimes some API keys/secrets are obvious and you can understand security impact and risk of exposing these keys. Please let me know what's the security risk involved in these keys:

1. Google Maps API Key
2. Fabric API key (probably can forge crash data)
3. Twitter/FB Consumer key and secret (no auth tokens)
4. Crashlytics SDK developer's token

Thanks

Comment: I posted a similar issue on the Firebase Android SDK github page: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1583. Hope someone serious will look at this.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps Api Key are now subject of billing as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing, thus you will want to protect it very well and same goes for Twitter that started to charge for some features in their API as per https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/08/16/has_your_twitter_app_stopped_working_heres_why.

So if they are not protected they can be hijacked from your application and used in your behalf and the usage charged to you.

Regarding the other keys I cannot comment on by now, once I don't have enough knowledge about them.

Comment: This answer differs a little from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542498/what-are-the-security-risks-with-including-google-map-api-key-in-gradle   wasn't api-key-restriction an opportunity then?

Comment: API key restriction is always recommended to be used, but in the end of the the day it can be bypassed.

Comment: "but in the end of the day it can be bypassed" -> could you please provide sources for that? I'd like to know how realistic such an attack is, since it's my personal bank account which would get billed.....

Comment: Google for `Android bypass api key restriction` and you will find links to several answers to your question, like [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/213260) in Security StackExchange..